# Mockito and EasyMock

Tags: mockito, easymock

In EasyMock when we want to record an expectation for a method that doesn't have a return type like `bookService.save();`, we just call the method before the replay.

How can we perform this with Mockito and what is the equivalent of `replay()` for Mockito?

My Test controller is

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addBookPost(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        bookService.save(book);
        MultipartFile bookImage = book.getBookImage();
        try {
            byte[] bytes = bookImage.getBytes();
            String name = book.getId() + ".png";
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(new File("src/main/resources/static/image/book/" + name)));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "redirect:bookList";
    }
```

This is my test

```
 @Test
     public void addBookClicked() throws Exception {

        Mockito.verify(bookService).save(book);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/book/add").with(user("admin").password("admin").roles("USER","ADMIN"))

                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())

                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("book"))
                .andExpect(view().name("addBook"))
                .andReturn();
    }
```

But it's wrong. How should I verify the call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mockito doesn't have replay mode.

From [this page](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mockito-vs-EasyMock) comparing the two frameworks (emphasis is mine):

> There only 2 things you can do with Mockito mocks - verify or stub.
>   Stubbing goes before execution and **verification afterwards**.

`replay` + `verify` operations with Easymock can be replaced with only `verify` with Mockito.
However with Mockito, the verification has to be performed **afterwards**.

Actually you invoke `Mockito.verify()` before the call to the backend. So it can only fail.
You used the EasyMock way by mixing a little things : you replaced EasyMock `replay()` by Mockito `verify()`.
But as said, `replay()` is not required and doesn't exist in Mockito.
So just do things according to the time chronology : invoke the method that has to invoke the mock and then assert with  `Mockito.verify()` that the mock was effectively invoked.

You should so write :

```
 @Test
 public void addBookClicked() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(get("/book/add").with(user("admin").password("admin").roles("USER","ADMIN"))

            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
            .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())

            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("book"))
            .andExpect(view().name("addBook"))
            .andReturn();

    Mockito.verify(bookService).save(book);
}
```

Comment: So it seems to have been solved only now I'm getting an error  org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "book.title" (addBook:24) and there seems to be no problem with my template addbook

Comment: You are welcome. About your new issue, you should try to use a debugger and set a breakpoint to watch the book value. If you didn't find to solve your issue, you should open a new question as it is another kind of issue.

Comment: but we use when in mockito exactly how we use expect in easy mock @davidxxx

Comment: `save()` returns nothing. So I don't see how it could change things. I think that you should edit the question with the EasyMock code, it would be much simpler to understand the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Both frameworks are similar but a tiny bit different.

EasyMock will want (by default) expectations for everything and then will verify everything.

Mockito will just record what happen and let pass everything. Like an EasyMock mock niceMock would do. You will get many `NullPointerExceptions` for none void methods along the way and add missing expectations. At the end, you can verify the calls you really wanted to make sure happened. Because of this architecture, you don't need to go in replay mode.

So, with EasyMock, the code will look like:

```
@Test
public void addBookClicked() throws Exception {

  bookService.save(book); // no expect or expectLastCall needed

  replay(bookService);

  mockMvc.perform(get("/book/add").with(user("admin").password("admin").roles("USER","ADMIN"))
      .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(model().attributeExists("book"))
      .andExpect(view().name("addBook"))
      .andReturn();

  verify(bookService);
}
```

and with Mockito

```
@Test
public void addBookClicked() throws Exception {

  mockMvc.perform(get("/book/add").with(user("admin").password("admin").roles("USER","ADMIN"))
      .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(model().attributeExists("book"))
      .andExpect(view().name("addBook"))
      .andReturn();

  Mockito.verify(bookService).save(book);

}
```

Note that Mockito will have a shorter syntax in this example. But it's not always the case. For instance, let's say you `save()` method returns a used id and you also want to make sure the method was called. You will end up with a duplicate call to `save()`:

```
@Test
public void addBookClicked() throws Exception {

  Mockito.when(bookService.save(book)).thenReturn(1L); // return the id

  mockMvc.perform(get("/book/add").with(user("admin").password("admin").roles("USER","ADMIN"))
      .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(model().attributeExists("book"))
      .andExpect(view().name("addBook"))
      .andReturn();

  Mockito.verify(bookService).save(book);
}
```

Comment: so in Mocktito we must always verify at the end , and mockito records what happened by itslf but when we have a return value , then we must use the mocktio when , then return . @Henri

Comment: The verify is optional for both frameworks. In your case, you want to make sure `save` is called so a verification is necessary. And yes, you need a `when` to return a value. You got it right.

Comment: can I update the question so u can confirm a thought of mine about testing jpa repositories @Henri

Comment: I've edited it a bit myself. However, you should not change the question if it changes the original sense.

Answer (score 1):

`verify(bookService).save(book)`

The verification can be set to expect verification in order, and/or number of times the mock should be called.

http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify

Comment: thanks but still doesn't work I will post the test method